# Simplification of a Residuum

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I had to find the Residuum $Res(f|z_k)$ for all Singularities $z_k$ for $f(z)=tan(z)$.
I got that.
which is:

$Res(f|\frac \pi2) = \lim_{z \to \frac \pi 2} (z-\frac \pi 2)\ tan(z) =  \lim_{z \to \frac \pi 2} (z-\frac \pi 2)\ \frac{\sin z}{\cos z}  $

but then the last step, I do not comprehend the formation:
$\lim_{z \to \frac \pi 2} (z-\frac \pi 2)\ \frac{\sin z}{\cos z} = \lim_{z \to \frac \pi 2} \frac{\sin z + (z-\frac \pi 2)\ \cos z}{- \sin z} = -1 $

how did we get $-\sin z$ in the denominator and the addition in nominator? and How do we get $-1$ as result?

Comment: It is just L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: but why would we use L'hopital here, we don't have an indeterminate form, cos z and sin z arent the same.

Comment: We do have a $\frac 0 0$ form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of poles of $\tan(z)$ is $\big\{z_k=\big({\frac1 2 +k}\big)\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z} \big\}$, so we have that at any of them, because they are all simple:
$$\lim_{z\to z_k}((z-z_k)\tan z)=\lim_{z\to z_{k}}\bigg(\sin z \frac{z-z_k}{\cos z}\bigg)=\lim_{z\to z_k}\frac{z\sin z-z_k\sin z}{\cos z}=_{L'Hopital \;rule}\lim_{z\to z_{k}}\frac{\sin z+z\cos z-z_k\cos z}{-\sin z}=\frac{\sin z_k}{-\sin z_k}=-1$$
The last step is by applying the L'Hôpital's rule for the indeterminate form $0/0$.
So $Res(f,z_k)=-1$, $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: how do we get $\frac{1}{-\sin z}$ from $\frac{z-z_k}{\cos z}$

Comment: Since it's an indeterminate form $0/0$, you apply the L'Hopital rule and derivate numerator and denominator. The derivative of $z-z_k$ is just $1$, and the derivative of $\cos z$ is $-\sin z$